# Meta_query with multiple keys and multiple values

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I have a WP Query code like below to check if have post match all post_meta > get that post, else create new post, but the result always show me a post have only `loaicua = cua-chinh` and `loaiphong = phong-khach` and i don't know why.

Can someone point out the error in the code below? I will appreciate any help.

```
<?php
foreach( $meta_array as $meta ) { $i++;
    if (!isset($page_query_args[$meta['key']])) {
        $page_query_args[$meta['key']]['key'] = $meta['key'];
        $page_query_args[$meta['key']]['value'][] = $meta['value'];
        $page_query_args[$meta['key']]['type'] = 'CHAR';
        $page_query_args[$meta['key']]['compare'] = 'IN';
    } else {
        $page_query_args[$meta['key']]['value'][] = $meta['value'];
    }
    if( $i == sizeof( $meta_array ) ) {
        $page_query_args = array_values($page_query_args);
    }
}

if( sizeof( $meta_array ) > 1 ) {
    $page_query_args['relation'] = 'AND';
}

$page_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => $page_query_args,
    )
);
```

Output of $page_query_args

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "loaicua"
    ["value"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "cua-chinh"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "CHAR"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(9) "loaiphong"
    ["value"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "phong-khach"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "phong-ngu"
      [2]=>
      string(12) "phong-tre-em"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "CHAR"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
  }
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the sentence "check if have post match all post_meta > get that post,"? It's very difficult to understand, and I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is `$meta_array` and where does it come from?

Comment: @TomJNowell sorry about that, I want to filter posts that only match all post_meta in meta_query, but the query filter also posts that does not have all post_meta or just have some post_meta of meta_query. And $meta_array is an ajax array from frontend for "value" in output above and it works fine